# C# / WPF - Partial declarations must not specify different base classes

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

Here's my NewWin Class inherited from Window (System.Windows.Window) Class.

```
public partial class NewWin : Window
{
    public NewWin()
    {
        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

And my MainWindow (WPF's Default) inherited from NewWin instead of Window.

```
public partial class MainWindow : NewWin
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Upon compilation there is an error message writing as followed:

> Partial declarations of 'Test.MainWindow' must not specify different base classes

With 'Test' being the name of my project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to MainWindow.xaml and change type of root element from Window to NewWin.

Comment: I probably must have added that I'm not an expert on xaml, so by root I assumed that you meant x:Class="Test.MainWindow" which was changed to x:Class="Test.NewWin", and that solved the problem.